# How to wrap a custom HandlerFunc

Tags: go

I have defined a `CustomHandler` (struct which implements `ServerHTTP`, and has a `HandlerFunc` that returns an error)

```golang
type CustomHandler struct{
  HandlerFunc func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error
}

type (c CustomHandler) ServerHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  err := c.Handeler.ServerHttp(w, r)
  // Handler error
}
```

How can I wrap my `CustomHandler`?

I have tried this, but I keep getting not enough arguments.

```golang
func myMiddle(h CustomHandler) CustomHandler {
  return h.CusomHandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    h.ServerHTTP(w, r)
    return nil
  })
}
```

Comment: Indicate the line of code where you get the error. Show the type definition for CustomHandler.

Comment: Have you mis-spelt `Handler`?

Comment: The error points to '})' and no I haven't mis-spelt Handler this time

Comment: You still mis-spelt it in the question title...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that:

```
type handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error

func (h handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := h(w, r); err != nil {
        ...
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    ...
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", handler(home))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First define `CustomHandler` like this:

```
type CustomHandler struct{}
```

then `ServeHTTP` like this:

```
func (c CustomHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", msg1)
}
```

See this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", CustomHandler{})
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}

type CustomHandler struct{}

func (c CustomHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", msg1)
}

var msg1 string = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Welcome Home</title>
</head>
<body>
Welcome Home
</body>
</html>
`
```

Then run the above code then open `http://127.0.0.1/`
output:

```
Welcome Home
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make so many spelling mistakes in your code.

- `ServerHTTP` should be `ServeHTTP`
- `Handeler` should be `Handler`
- `ServerHttp` should be `ServeHTTP`
- `CusomHandlerFunc` should be `CustomHandlerFunc`

When you have fixed these misspellings, you have a better chance that your code works.